# Python - Getting text using selenium from text node

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, textnode

I'm trying to scrape some information from a website using Selenium and Python and sometimes there's texts like this **HZS stonks remaining...** that does not have any name or label that I can get the text by:

[image: snapshot]

I can get the `mkt-card` class element easily and I assume that I can somehow get it from the `mkt-card` element but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML:

[image: snapshot]

the desired element is within a text node and is within it's parent element `<div class="mkt-card">`

---

### Solution

To print the text ***HZS stonks remaining 0.14*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.mkt-card").text)
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mkt-card']").text)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get the text in question:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
    <div class="mkt-card"><div>some text</div><div class="error"></div>"HZS stonks remaining 0.14"</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
stonks_text = soup.select_one('div.error').next_sibling
print(stonks_text)
```

This returns `"HZS stonks remaining 0.14"`

Next time do not post screenshots, but actual text.